# Proving that $\lfloor x + k \rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor + k$

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

How to prove that $\lfloor x + k \rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor + k$ when $k$ is an integer?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\lfloor x\rfloor \le x<\lfloor x\rfloor +1$, hence $\lfloor x\rfloor +k\le x+k<\lfloor x\rfloor+k +1$, so that the integer $\lfloor x\rfloor +k$ fulfills the defining property of $\lfloor x+k\rfloor$.

Answer (score -1):

1) ⌊x⌋ = x - {x}
2) {k} = 0
3) ⌊x + k⌋ = x + k - {x + k}
According to point 2:
{x + k} = {x}
And from there on just replace the parts in point 3.
x + k - {x + k} = x + k - {x} = x - {x} + k = ⌊x⌋ + k